# capture permission granted complete event

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, permissions

I'm creating an app using flash cc. I needed storage permission. It turns out I needed to ask user the permission for using storage devices. I can ask user for permission and it is working fine. I use examples from this website: https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/release-note/fp_24_air_24_release_notes.html
 But my problem is I wasn't able to capture the complete event for accessing the storage permission. Because of that I couldn't run codes after I get access to storage. Is it possible to capture complete event for granting any permission?

the code I used:

```
var file:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("somefile.txt");
trace("url_txt:" + file.url);
file.addEventListener(PermissionEvent.PERMISSION_STATUS, function permissionStatusHandler(e:PermissionEvent):void
{                        
    file.removeEventListener(PermissionEvent.PERMISSION_STATUS, permissionStatusHandler);
    if(e.status == PermissionStatus.GRANTED)
    {                            
        myTextLoader.load(new URLRequest(file.url));
        myTextLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadTextComp);
        myTextLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loadingTextError);
    }
    else
    {
        showPermissionError();
    }
}
);
try
{
    trace("Requesting permission");
    file.requestPermission();
}
catch(error:Error)
{
    trace("Request permission error");
}
```

**UPDATE:**

The above code seems to work fine. But the problem occurs when I tried to request for same permission twice at different time. I've another question. Can we add description while we request permission? A lot of app seems to be adding description why the app need that particular permission. Is it possible do achieve this from flash as3? I've looked into web but couldn't find anything. And how to request permission for `READ_PHONE_STATE`?

Comment: thanks for the fast reply. I'll check it out.

Comment: is `onRequestPermissionsResult` for as3 or android studio?

Comment: Show your code, maybe? "Wasn't able to capture" sounds weird.

Comment: While testing it, I encountered a totally different problem. While I have no troubles with the event itself, calling the **requestPermission** does not provide me with any options, but immediately fires the **PermissionEvent** with the current permission instead. I built it with AIR 24 SDK to AIR 24 runtime (Flash Player 35) and testing it on Android 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I figured it out. Prerequisites:

- AIR runtime 24+
- Android 6+
- APK must be published with WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission (otherwise it is automatically **DENIED** - that what I was stuck at)

Then, this code works for me just fine, it displays Android's "Grant Permission" dialog and then outputs GRANTED or DENIED with regard to my choice. The **Log** class is just a debug panel of my own, you can change **Log.log** calls to **trace** or grab it here (it has no dependencies): https://bitbucket.org/thydmitry/ru.delimiter/src/9083fb46ce1c/classes/ru/delimiter/utils/

```
package
{
    import ru.delimiter.utils.Log;

    import flash.filesystem.File;

    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.PermissionEvent;

    import flash.permissions.PermissionStatus;

    public class Permissions extends Sprite
    {
        private var F:File;

        public function Permissions() 
        {
            if (stage) onStage();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStage);
        }

        private function onStage(e:Event = null):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStage);

            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

            Log.create(this, true);

            Log.log("[Permissions Test] started");
            Log.log("File.permissionStatus:", File.permissionStatus);

            F = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("somefile.txt");
            F.addEventListener(PermissionEvent.PERMISSION_STATUS, onPerm);

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
        }

        private function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            F.requestPermission();
        }

        private function onPerm(e:PermissionEvent):void
        {
            Log.log("User's decision:", e.status.toUpperCase());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does PERMISSION_STATUS executes right away or it executes only after the permission status changed?

Comment: It turns out my above code was working as it is. The problem is I need to read two text files. If the app couldn't find the first one, then it will try to read the second one. I put the same code when the second text file try to read. But on the second time, it throws error on device. It works fine in pc. Why it is throwing error? I know, I can't request multiple permissions simultaneously but I'm not requesting permission simultaneously. However, I'm requesting for same permission twice but not the same time. Am I not allow to request for same permission twice?

Comment: @TheGunners As far as I tested the code above, once user has willingly granted the permission, any consequent **requestPermission** just fires **PermissionEvent** with **status** set to **granted** immediately. I haven't encountered any exceptions while doing so. Moreover, once user has granted the permission, it remains granted even if you close and reopen the app, unless you turn the given permission off in the application settings (In this case the behavior reverts to initial and will require calling **requestPermission** again).

Comment: I don't know why but it's showing error. But I've ditched the code. Now I only request permission one time. And another question, is it possible to add description while requesting permissions?

Comment: @TheGunners Description? What kind of description? Do you mean to the "Grant Permission" Android dialog?

Comment: Description like "this let app store and access information like photos on your phone".

Comment: Not the default dialog but our own.

Comment: @TheGunners You cannot avoid the default Android dialog (I believe) or it could become an infinitely-sized loophole for phishing. "Dear user please allow this app access the storage and your phone and your credit card details of course you can trust this 146% trustworthy confirmation 100% legit!!!" Just design an info screen in your app that explains what is going to happen the next click.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tested your codes. It works too. It was helpful. Thanks