# Using the DataShare ANE

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, ane

I have been trying to share an image with the datashare ANE with FlashDevelop: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/datashare-native-extension.html

At first, it was working great (AIR 24), but since I updated the AIR sdk (I am using AIR 26), it doesn't seem to work anymore. I get this:

```
[Fault] exception, information=Error: Error #3001: File or directory access denied.
in flash.filesystem::FileStream/open
```

But my application.xml file already has

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

It seems to be coming from the Android version, since it works on on old phone running android 4.4.4. It doesn't work on Android 7.0. Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: My guess is the permissions policy that has chaged since Android 6. You might find this thread useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44756809/capture-permission-granted-complete-event/44765197#44765197

Comment: Oh that's great! I added the request at the start of the application and now it's working again. So now we have to manually ask for permissions with this workaround?

Comment: It is not a *workaround*, it is the way permissions work in the newest versions of Android and iOS: instead of asking user for all the permissions at the installation time you need to request for one permission at a time the moment your app needs them. Once permission is granted, it stays so unless user deliberately turns it off in the app settings (then you can/need to request this permission once again).