# Saving Image In Adobe Animate Air For Android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, actionscript, air, adobe-animate

**See My Code. I read many blogs and also checked my XML permission all done. Image exporting into my pc but when I published APK. and I installed it on my phone. my code does not work properly. I can't saw any save image and folder in my gallery. what can I do.**

```
 stop();
            import flash.filesystem.File;
            import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
            import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
            import flash.net.FileReference; //add this

            import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;
            import com.adobe.images.PNGEncoder;

            var date: Date = new Date();

        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onSavePictureButtonClicked);

        function onSavePictureButtonClicked(event: MouseEvent): void {

            var ImageSaverBMD: BitmapData = new BitmapData(Object(parent).mc_canvas.width, 
            Object(parent).mc_canvas.height);
            ImageSaverBMD.draw(Object(parent).mc_canvas);
            var jpgEncoder: JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(100);
            var jpgBytes: ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(ImageSaverBMD);
            Object(parent).mc_canvas.scaleX = 1;
            Object(parent).mc_canvas.scaleY = 1;
            var file_name: String;

            if (date.getMonth() < 12)
                file_name = '0' + date.getMonth() + '-';
            else
                file_name = date.getMonth() + '-';

            if (date.getDate() < 10)
                file_name += '0' + date.getDate() + '-' + date.getFullYear();
            else
                file_name += date.getDate() + '-' + date.getFullYear();

            file_name = 'Picture ' +
                file_name + '_' +
                date.getHours() + '.' +
                date.getMinutes();

            var myFile: File = File.userDirectory.resolvePath("KidsColoring/" + file_name + ".jpg");

            trace(myFile.nativePath); // C:\Documents and Settings\userName\My Documents\AIR Test 
            Object(parent).nativee.text = myFile.nativePath;


            var fs: FileStream = new FileStream();
            fs.open(myFile, FileMode.WRITE);
            fs.writeBytes(jpgBytes, 0, jpgBytes.length);
            fs.close();

            Object(parent).SaveDialog.gotoAndPlay(2);
        }
```

Comment: Probably, this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44765197/4687633 ? Permissions should not only be set but also requested explicitly as well.

Comment: thanks, I added this permission and allowed storage permission on the phone. my code properly worked and also shows my save dialog box.(your image have been saved) but I can't find image and folder on my phone. i want to save image in my phone root storage.

See This Image:-  [Image](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KkhBvI1MLQFND-n4szi5zKV21gs6XQKZ?usp=sharing)

Comment: Well, you obviously save it to user's home folder, which is widely used on desktops and laptops, but I don't think I have ever used it on mobiles. Who knows where it is.