# How to implement run-time Permissions on as3?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, permissions, adobe

I was triying to made an Android app with as3 in Adobe Animate 2020 but i have a problem to give permissions to Read and write into the device, my app needs to save info into a txt or csv external file but this error appers. Im already give the permissions at the manifest but doesnt works propertly. Any ideas?

This is my code:

```
package {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;;
import flash.filesystem.*;
import flash.filesystem.File;


public class Writing extends MovieClip {

    var file: File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("test.txt");
    var str: String = "Hello.";

    public function Writing() {

        file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileSaved);
        file.save(str);

    }

    function fileSaved(event: Event): void {
        trace("Done.");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: In Android 6+ and AIR runtime 24+ you need to explicitly request for certain permissions **even** if you allow those in your manifest. Read my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44765197/4687633

Comment: I just read your answer but in my code i get some errors about the Log function. 1172 Doesnt find the definition ru.delimiter.utils:Log.

Comment: Please don't just copy the code but also read (that's the point of learning new things) the answer. It explains what the **Log** class is and how to avoid that error.