# Can't I access portable/external SD in Android 7.1.2? It was working on Android 4.4

Tags: android, actionscript-3, sdk, air

I have commercial tablets running on Android 4.4. I made a simple app with some buttons, video's and txt files. The video's and the txt files are stored on the external sd card so I can change the content without changing the app.

In my code I used (AIR SDK as3):

```
"file:///mnt/external-sd/folder/";
```

as reference to the folder. But on the newer commercial tablets Android 7.1.2. is running and this doesn't work anymore. I tried to change the filepath in 100 different ways based on what I found online what this could be.. It is making me nuts.
I have set the write and read permission, just to be sure, in the manifest (I didn't needed them in the older version). But nothing changed...

I think something else might be the problem? Am I missing something?

Comment: The path of a removable micro sd card can be found using the second item returned by getExternalFilesDirs().

Comment: Have you requested runtime permission to access the external card? Runtime permissions have been added since 4.4

Comment: I double the permissions comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44765197/4687633

Comment: @blackapps is this also possible in as3/AIR SDK? I can't figure it out and can only find it written in Java.

Comment: Michael and @organis you were right. Runtime permissions were not set up. I have to dig deeper in that, because I can't get it to work at once. the app has multiple files in the external sd (txt and video) but I hope you only have to grant access once?

Comment: Yes. Once user permits you, the app keeps that permission and doesn't get to bother user ever again.